# Issue with smali code

Tags: android, disassembly, smali

Let's assume the following sample code

```
public static int addition() {
int result = 1;
for(int i = 1; i < 10000 ; i++)
result = result + i;
}
```

and the corresponding smali code (0002 is next to the if-ge):

```
const/4 v0,#int 1
move v1,v0
const/16 v2,#int 10000
if-ge v0,v2,<0x0a>
add-int/2addr v1,v0
add-int/lit8 v0,v0,#int 1
goto <0002>
return v1
```

I tried to understand the corresponding smali (assembly) code, but came across a line that makes no sense to me right now (marked with ???). If I'm not mistaken the value of v1 is increased each round by the value of v0, which makes no sense at all - first round: v1 = 2 ; second round v1 = 4 and so on

```
put 1 into register v0          // v0 = 1 
move value register v0 into v1  // v0 = 1 ; v1 = 1
put 10000 into register v2      // v0 = 1 ; v1 = 1 ; v2 = 10000 
if v0 >= v2 goto 0x0a           // v0 = 1 ; v1 = 1 ; v2 = 10000 
v1 = v1 + v0           (???)    // v0 = 1 ; v1 = 2 ; v2 = 10000
v0 = 1 + v0                     // v0 = 2 ; v1 = 2 ; v2 = 10000
goto 0x02
return v1
```

I guess I'm misunderstanding one of the lines. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would be correct if the code would be `result = result + i;`. Maybe a typo?

Comment: @Nils: Can you confirm that this was a typo?

Comment: Ah, yeah, there is a typo. Sorry about that. I modified it above.

Comment: Nevertheless I still don't understand why v1 is incremented and returned. Can anyone translate me the initial two loops of that smali code maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that matches the java code that you posted. `v1` is `result` and `v0` is `i`.

To rephrase your analysis of the code:

```
put 1 into variable i           // i = 1 
move value i into result        // i = 1 ; result = 1
put 10000 into register v2      // i = 1 ; result = 1 ; v2 = 10000 
if i >= v2 goto 0x0a            // i = 1 ; result = 1 ; v2 = 10000 
result = i + result             // i = 1 ; result = 2 ; v2 = 10000
i = 1 + i                       // i = 2 ; result = 2 ; v2 = 10000
goto 0x02
return result
```

Your question is about the `add-int/2addr v1,v0` instruction specifically, which is analogous to the `result = result + i;` line in the original java.

Comment: see answer / not enough space here

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help JesusFreke. My bad. Apparently I interpreted my result+i as result plus 1 for whatever reason and got confused. Now it makes perfect sense. Sorry for that.